# Error when adding Autocorrelation in GAMM

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model

I am fitting a Generalized Additive Mixed Models (GAMM) model to
establish possible relationship between explanatory variables (Temperature,Humidity,Rainfall and Wind speed) and HFMD disease data. I am using weekly time-series for 8 years which are auto-correlated.

I want to make a comparison between GAM and GAMM model with adding the autocorrelation in the model.
But i'm having a trouble to come out with the result. It displays an error from GAMM model. I exactly reffer the coding by **Gavin Simpson** as stated [here] (https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/modelling-seasonal-data-with-gam/). But the output give some errors.

This is head of my data:

[image]

In which, there are 52/53 weeks for each year in the data (Including the leap year). The week repeated for each year.

The models formulation I have come up with is:

```
GAM=gam(HFMD2~s(Temp2,bs='cc',k=20)+s(Humidity2,bs='cc',k=20)+s(Rainfall2,bs='cc',k=20)+s(Windspeed2,bs='cc',k=20)+s(Time2,k=32),data=DataJ,family=nb(),method="REML")

ctrl=list(niterEM =0, msVerbose = TRUE, optimMethod="L-BFGS-B")

GAMM=gamm(HFMD2~s(Temp2,bs='cc',k=12)+Humidity2+Rainfall2+s(Windspeed2,bs='cc',k=20)+s(Time2,k=32),data=DataJ,family=negbin(theta=4.183),correlation =corARMA(form=~1|Year2,p=1),control=ctrl)
```

But when I add the correlation term in the GAMM model, the output come out with an error:

```
Error in lme.formula(fixed = fixed, random = random, data = data, correlation = correlation,  : 
  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
```

I just wonder which part are wrong in my coding? Is my coding can be considered?

I really hope that someone will help me to resolve this problem. And a big thank for it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try different solvers/given more iterations to `nlmib`.

Comment: can you give me some example for it? Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but I am currently running several models with the same explanatory variables and autocorrelation.

Got several errors and solved by tweaking the `mgcv.vc.logrange` parameter which is 25 by default.
Try reducing it to (20, 15, 10) and see what happens.

```
options("mgcv.vc.logrange") # to show current value

options(mgcv.vc.logrange = 20) # to set desired value
```